# How does getting and setting affect assigning of variables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings, getter-setter

C# Homework question: we're doing an exercise in `getting` and `setting`, and accessing variables in a very convoluted manner.

I have a user message being generated by an `if...then` loop:

```
if (condition a)
{String userMessage = "foo";}
else if (condition b)
{String userMessage = "bar";}
...etc.
```

I am using a `getter` to access the `userMessage` variable...

```
public String Result
{
  get { return userMessage; }
}
```

...then outputting the message to the console.

```
Console.WriteLine(thegame.Result);
```

I'm receiving an informational message from Visual Studio 2010 that on the four lines where I am assigning a value to `String userMessage =....`, `Warning  5   The variable 'userMessage' is assigned but its value is never used`.

Is this message received because of the roundabout way in which I'm accessing the variable? or is the a symptom of a larger problem? All the references to the message online are in the context of declaring a variable that's never used...but I am using the `userMessage` variable in this case. What's causing the error?

Comment: Check your scoping. You keep declaring new variables inside of if statements. Once you leave the code block {} the variable is gone, and in these cases -- never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the variable in the scope of the condition:

```
string userMessage; // class scope


...

if (condition) {
     String userMessage = "blah"; // only available until the closing brace
} // out of scope here
```

So that is the warning. You're creating a variable that is scoped only to one line.. but never using it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (condition a)
{userMessage = "foo";}
else if (condition b)
{userMessage = "bar";}
...etc.
```

it' because you're defining different variables in every condition.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're defining a *new* variable called `userMessage` in your `if` block. Take the `String` modifiers out of the `if` block and you should be fine.